# How to use same stored procedure both insert,update and delete in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

my problem same [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554976/using-same-stored-procedure-for-both-insert-and-update-in-entity-framework).but i don't understand solution.in my SP parameter "@OperationType" determine that what is type of operation.(if 1 then Insert,if 2 then Update,if 3 then Delete)
my stored procedure is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[JobOperation] (
@ID                       INT = NULL OUTPUT,
@JobTitle                 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@JobLevel                 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Des                      NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@IsDbCommandCommitted     BIT = 0 OUTPUT,
@DbCommitError            VARCHAR(200) = NULL OUTPUT,
@OperationType            INT = NULL,
@LanguageID               INT = NULL
)
AS
IF @operationType = 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO ....

        SELECT @ID = MAX(ID)
        FROM   JOB

        SET @IsDbCommandCommitted = 1
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @DbCommitError = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
ELSE 
IF @OperationType = 2
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE JOB
        ......

        SET @IsDbCommandCommitted = 1
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @DbCommitError = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
ELSE 
IF @OperationType = 3
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE 
        FROM   JOB
        WHERE  ID = @ID

        SET @IsDbCommandCommitted = 1
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @DbCommitError = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

any idea?

Comment: did you tried anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pass parameter Using EF](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Entity-Framework-Call-Stored-Procedure-with-Parameters-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Follow this tutorial to pass the parameter to your SP using EF, this should solve your query

Comment: i using windows app not asp.net.

Comment: c# and EF process won't change in that as well as far as I'm aware off

Comment: when click "Get Column Information" parameter not showed and show this message : "The selected Stored Procedure or function returns no columns"

Comment: yes because you are not returning anything from the SP

Comment: i want to doing Operation not return some columns.

Comment: entities.SearchCustomers(txtCustomerName.Text.Trim());

this way you can pass 1/2/3 as your input